# iTunes reject app for date of birth

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am iOS developer. I made an application for chat which required registration for go into app.
In registration screen, it require DATE OF BIRTH. Apple reject my app for more than 3 times because of DATE OF BIRTH field. I have told them that into our privacy policy we described that user's age must be more than 17 so, we need to add this field for date verification.

But, still they are rejecting my app.

Please help me.

Comment: Why do you need the date of birth? You could just ask for their age - or even better, ask if they are over 17, which is all you actually care about.

Comment: @girish_pro, do you have source code of THVideoFaceSwapper?

Comment: @Mehul do you have "THVideoFaceSwapper" code

Comment: @ImranAhmed No I don't have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, I am able to make app live on App store.
I remove DATE OF BIRTH field and add AGE field where user just select age, not birthdate.

And then, Apple make it live.

Answer (score 4):

**From "App Store Review Guidelines 17. Privacy":**

> 17.2
>   Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected
>
> 17.3 Apps may ask for date of birth (or use other age-gating mechanisms) only for the purpose of complying with applicable
>   children's privacy statutes, but must include some useful
>   functionality or entertainment value regardless of the user's age

So try to explain them why exactly you need to ask for the birthdate and try to offer another approach for people under 17.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really something that anyone other than Apple could help you with.

Here is a link to the guidelines for your app to be published. https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

And here is a link to their support page. https://developer.apple.com/contact/

Best of luck.

Comment: thanks for replay. I had communicate with apple into Resolution Center. But they stuck with DATE OF BIRTH.

Comment: @girish_pro They can be quite resilient but if you have a strong case for why you need a birthday then you just need to convince the team member who approves it or escalate it to someone who can. They get several requests for things like this so their automatic nature is to decline.

Comment: yes. You are right. I had submitted another app before 4-5 month. They just rejected at first try. then I succeeded to convince them and they make it live. But this time, we are not listing to me. I added Appeal just before 5 min. I hope it will help